# Reading a text file in java, then writing a new file

Tags: java, text, bufferedreader, streamwriter, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to format the printwriter on this code to only print lowercase and remove all non-alphabetic characters.

Cheers

```
import java.io.*;

public class TextFile {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
                File file1 = new File("PG.txt");
                File file2 = new File("newfile.txt"); 

                BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1)));
                PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file2)));

                int ch;
                while ((ch = in.read()) != -1){
                    out.write(ch);

                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
    }       
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Where is the logic part for the printing? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You need an `if` statement in your `while` loop to eliminate the non-alphabetic characters.